# Create base class for 2 business objects / view models with mutual properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, radix

At the moment I have a Teststep.cs Business Object and a viewmodel pendant which is bound to the system.web.MVC namespace and having additional properties like IsDirty.

In the presentation layer I have 2 views (Template (write/read + more functions) and Testplan(readonly nearly)) which show different properties of the TeststepViewModel.

Should I create a TeststepViewModelBase and create another 2 ViewModels TemplateTeststepVM and TestplanTeststepVM?

Whats the gain for that?

Comment: You question is very vague.  What are you actually trying to accomplish in the end?

Comment: I just want to take the right architectural approach with viewmodel/models when I could/should actually use a base class. Maybe I am totally wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to have a 1-1 mapping between ViewModels and Views. It is perfectly sensible to have a single ViewModel shared between two Views, provided that it makes sense.

A ViewModel is a version of the model that is used by the Views. If the ViewModel you have currently represents a logical component, it makes sense to share it between the two Views. If the Views provide different perspectives on the same business object then you are probably on the right track.

However this does not mean that you should use a single ViewModel for multiple Views by *default*. I've worked on projects with a single enormous ViewModel - over 1000 lines - which sat behind a dozen Views. That is not a good pattern and is difficult to maintain.

Comment: I have 2 views. Both show data from the TeststepViewModel class which is mapped to the Teststep class. The testplan view shows partly other properties tan the template view. Should I divide now my TeststepViewModel into 2 ViewModels? Hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: @Pascal The question was clear enough to me from the start, and I don't think I need to change my answer. Is my answer clear to you?

Comment: I understand your answer not completey therefore I have rephrased my question/choosed other words. Should I now use 2 TeststepViewModels each for its own view. And if yes what is the advantage of that vs 1 TeststepViewModel. Actually imho a Teststep.cs and a TeststepViewModel is enough (of course I still have a CreateTeststepViewModels with other rules etc...)

Comment: @Pascal "Should I now use 2 TeststepViewModels each for its own view" - No. You should stay with 1 ViewModel.

Comment: The advantage of 2 ViewModels is that they are smaller and simpler. Just like 1 large class, or two small classes - if they perform the same functions, keep 1 class. If they are separate objects, make 2 classes.